# Advanced routing in rails : Constraints mixed with devise helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

Im looking to do something very specific i guess. I searched but didnt find an answer. I m a beginner in rails so be kind please :)
I m working on a website in rails 5.2 (with devise) which has to be accessible in a local network and with a public access too.
Routing has to be different for private ips and public ips and unauthenticated users.
Im trying to do something like this :

```
if (unauthenticated && public_network?)
  { root to: 'pages#public' } 
  { "*path" to: 'pages#public' }
else 
  { root to: 'pages#home' }
```

From outside people will be redirected to a specific signed in interface (pages#public with a different layout) for all routes of the site. 
When they are authenticated or with private ip the website will respond with pages#home

So i tried to do something like this in the first lines of my route.rb :

```
  unauthenticated :user do
    // Catch all routes and redirect to public method in pages ctrl for all publics ips
    get '*path', to: 'pages#public',
      constraints: lambda { |request| !request.remote_ip.in? ['127.0.0.1' , '172.18.0.1'] }
    get '/', to: 'pages#public',
      constraints: lambda { |request| !request.remote_ip.in? ['127.0.0.1' , '172.18.0.1'] }
    // And for the unauthenticated users on the Lan :
    root to: 'pages#home'
  end
```

and after this the rest of the routing behavior...

I tought this will work but it didnt.
It still works for the privates ips but on publics ips i m always redirected to pages#public even if im authenticated.
I m open to every solutions whitch can help me.

Thanks :)

Comment: I would start with fixing this: `request.remote_ip != '127.0.0.1' && '172.18.0.1'`.  This is not correct syntax. Do something like: `!request.remote_ip.in ? ['127.0.0.1' , '172.18.0.1']`

Comment: Thanks for this syntax advice :) i changed it but the behavior is still the same.

Comment: Can you, please, provide some pseudocode to express the desired routing behaviour. E.g.: `if (authenticated && private_network?) { ... } else if (unauthenticated && !public_network?) { ... } else { ... }`?

Comment: I edited my post with pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
unauthenticated :user do
  # `public_network?` is a placeholder for your specific checks
  constraints ->(request) { public_network? } do
    root to: 'pages#public'
    get '*path', to: 'pages#public'
  end
end

authenticated :user do
  root to: 'pages#home'
  get '/', to: 'pages#home'
end
```

Another issue is that both `"public"` and `"home"` are the actions of the same controller. It is not a big deal for the test application, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. I m going to make a specific controller for public method.